# test dtm 1 on the basis of dtm..so that 1 can predict the categories of dtm1

Tags: r, tm

### library functions

```
     library(tm)
     library(e1071)
     library(plyr)
```

### Inserting the journal names to be categorized

```
sample = c(
    "An Inductive Inference Machine",
    "Computing Machinery and Intelligence",
    "On the translation of languages from left to right",
    "First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC",
    "The Rendering Equation")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sample))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument,language="english")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

### term document matrix as training set

```
inspect(dtm)
Category=c("Machine learning","Artificial intelligence","Compilers","Computer   architecture","Computer graphics")
```

### declaration of the categories

```
my.data=data.frame(as.matrix(dtm),Category)
my.data 
sample = c(
    "gprof: A Call Graph Execution Profiler",
    "Architecture of the IBM System/360",
    "A Case for Redundant Arrays of Inexpensive Disks (RAID)",
    "Determining Optical Flow",
    "A relational model for large shared data banks",
    "some complementarity problems of z and lyoponov like transformations on       edclidean  jordan algebra")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sample))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument,language="english")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
dtm1 <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

### term document matrix as testing set

```
inspect(dtm1)
```

Comment: yaa..im new to this site...surely incorporate ur suggestions..btw i want to predict the categories of the second set using the first set..plzz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your sample data has absolutely no overlapping terms, so there's not really much you can do there. The `tm` library doesn't assign meaning to words, it just measures their correlation. So you need to supply enough overlapping data so that is has a chance of matching up new input to an existing corpus.

Once you actually have real data, you have many options on how you want to build a model. You can use a kNN classifier like that in the `class` package, or a decision tree like that in the `rpart` package, or a neural network like that in the `nnet` package. There are examples of each of those in [this presentation](http://web.letras.up.pt/bhsmaia/EDV/apresentacoes/Bradzil_Classif_withTM.pdf). But it's up to you to decide what's right for your data. That part is not a programming related question.

Comment: can i have ur mail id?..i can mail u the set of data which has enough overlapping terms..due to lack of space i can"t post here in the cmmnt box

Comment: @user3675487 I'm sorry, I can't analyze your data for you. I would follow the examples in the presentation I linked. You will need to decide for yourself which method is appropriate for your data. If you are unsure, I suggest you consult a statistician.

Comment: actually i have tried many combinations ...stacking the train and test set ..then using the "head" as train set..but some how the output is not desirable..